# jQuery: Display array values with markup / different divider

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

To get an array of values from multiple checked checkboxes, I am using jQuery map/get function:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(_, el) {
    return $(el).val();
}).get();
```

This will return array with checked values, like this one: `['1', '2']`

Now I would like to display the result in a table cell, but the result looks not nice. Instead of (currently) writing "1,2,3" it should be (minimum solution) "1, 2, 3" or (better):

```
1
2
3
```

How can that be achieved?

```js
$('#save_value').click(function() {
    var sel = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(_, el) {
        return $(el).val();
    }).get();
    
    alert(sel);
    
    $("#result").html(sel);
})
```

```css
#result {
  border: solid 1px #232323;  
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


1 <input  id="ad_Checkbox1" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
2 <input  id="ad_Checkbox2" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2" />
3 <input  id="ad_Checkbox3" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3" />
4 <input  id="ad_Checkbox4" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4" />
<input type="button" id="save_value" name="save_value" value="Save" />

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Use join `$("#result").html(sel.join(' ,'));`

Comment: Brilliant - that simple !! Works perfect for me.
So if you add your comment as a real answer I can upvote and accept your help. Thx again!

Comment: I think no need. Glad to help :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `$("#result")` equals `a table cell` you mentioned...

```js
$('#save_value').click(function() {
    var sel = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(_, el) {
        return $(el).val();
    }).get();
    
    alert(sel);
    
    $("#result1").html(sel.join(', '));
    $("#result2").html(sel.join('</br>'));
})
```

```css
#result {
  border: solid 1px #232323;  
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


1 <input  id="ad_Checkbox1" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
2 <input  id="ad_Checkbox2" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2" />
3 <input  id="ad_Checkbox3" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3" />
4 <input  id="ad_Checkbox4" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4" />
<input type="button" id="save_value" name="save_value" value="Save" />

<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly what I was looking for!